# How to stop mongodump safely?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I started a mongo dump and my database is with 95% of storage filled, and I am downloading to my local machine the bson file. 
But it is very slow and I am afraid to stop mongo dump to increase server storage size,  and one observation I am downloading a database to change to mongo atlas because I think it is easier to administrate.
Is there any command to stop mongodump safely?

Answer (score 0):

`mongodump` is a process that dump the data from your DB, it is not supposed to be stopped after performing some operations rather than others, but even stopping it not safely (e.g. sending an interrupt signal):

- Your DB will just release the read lock for mongodump
- The worst that could happen on your machine is having a malformed BSON